# How do I get iTunes in Virtualbox to detect my iPad?

Tags: virtualbox, itunes

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit Host and WIndows XP SP2 64-bit as Guest. My Virtualbox is version 4.3.20 and I have the Extension Pack installed. I added myself to vboxusers, and the iPad is redirecting properly, but iTunes can't detect it. In other words, Windows can see the iPad as a imaging device, but iTunes cannot see it.

**Specs:**

- Apple iPad 4th Generation IOS 7.1.2
- Host: Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit
- Guest: Windows XP SP2 64-bit
- **Note:** I did "hack" the iTunes installation file with the instructions [here](http://skunkwerks.wordpress.com/2008/04/13/getting-itunes-to-work-with-windows-xp-x64/). However, I have not followed the second set of instructions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some solutions that solved such problems for some people.

**Solution one : Driver**

The driver chosen by Microsoft may be unsuitable for the iPad;
Windows automatically using its own driver and not the Apple one.

1. Start up Device Manager
2. Double-click the iPhone (under Portable Devices)
3. Select the Driver tab and click "Update Driver"
   4 Click "Browse my computer"
4. Navigate to `c:\program files\common files\apple`
5. It should recognize the driver to install
6. After installation, reboot if the iPad is not recognized

**Solution two : Reinstall**

Alternatively, you could
extract the latest iTunes via 7-zip
and install (repair) the file `AppleMobleDeviceSupport.msi`.

**Solution three : Restore the iPad**

1. Disconnect the USB cable from the iPad, but leave the other end of the cable connected to your computer's USB port.
2. Turn off iPad: Press and hold the Sleep/Wake button for a few seconds until the red slider appears, then slide the slider. Wait for iPad to turn off.
3. While pressing and holding the Home button, reconnect the USB cable to iPad. When you reconnect the USB cable, iPad should power on.
4. Continue holding the Home button until you see the "Connect to iTunes" screen.
5. If necessary, open iTunes. You should see a "recovery mode" alert. Use iTunes to restore iPad.

Comment: The driver method doesn't work. Does the fact that I used the instructions in the last "note" change anything?

Comment: Please give more information about what you do and what happens. It's especially interesting if "Browse my computer", once you browse to the iTunes folder, does find some compatible driver (a screenshot will then be useful).

Comment: It just shows a random .inf configuration file and that is the only file in the ...\common files\apple\drivers

Comment: Which file is it (can you post it) and what happens if you choose that file?

Comment: Ok, I'll take a screnn

Comment: I will award the bounty for your try, and the screenshot will be posted shortly.